# Saving ODB File by Python: error attempt to truncate read only table

Tags: python-2.7, abaqus

I want to read ODB file and then add a field, and save the resulting ODB file.
The coode is very easy (given below).
But I get the error message:
OdbError: database save failed. **error attempt to truncate read only table.

Probably, the problem is in the ODB file, not in code itself.

Has anyone an idea what can be wrong there?

The code is:

```
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbMaterial import *
from odbSection import *
from numpy import fabs as fabs
import numpy as np
import sys
import math
import os
import datetime
from types import IntType
print('       Reading ODB    ' ) 
odb = openOdb(path='iog.odb') 
odb.save()
odb.close()
```

Comment: Please tell us how are you running the script - from the command line, from within the CAE session, ...

Comment: Thank you. i run the script from Abaqus: File - Run Script. i have a line in the code  odb = odbAccess.openOdb(path="Job-1.odb", readOnly=False). I checkjed the ODB file - it is not "read-only". But it still gives the error, when I have "save" command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `odbAccess.openOdb` method, the error "*OdbError: Database save failed. ***ERROR: Attempt to truncate read only table*" should only occur if the Odb has been opened with the optional argument `readOnly=True`. In my experience and according to the docs, the default value for this method is `readOnly=False`, which means you should be able to read and write. However, you can try to make it explicit by adding the optional argument, such as:

```
import odbAccess
odb = odbAccess.openOdb(path="Job-1.odb", readOnly=False)
```

If this still fails, I suspect that the file permissions have been changed. For example, in Windows you can right-click the .odb file, select "Properties", and see whether the "Read-only" attribute has been checked.

Answer (score 0):

If you opened the same file .odb in CAE as readonly=true (box checked), no matter how you define readOnly=false in your code, and reload the odb again and again, the error keeps coming, Even if you use command line instead of Run Script.

This can be solved by closing the same named file in CAE or GUI, or reload it with readOnly=false, and run the code with readonly=false (box unchecked).